# How can I replace Thread.sleep() in an infinite loop?

Tags: java, multithreading

I have an infinite loop inside my main, it runs a job which is also an infinite loop, and wait for it to throw an error. Then it sleeps for a given amount of time and starts the task again.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    while (true) {
        try {
            MyClass myClass = new MyClass();
            myClass.startInfiniteLoop();
        }
        catch (SomeException ex) {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(MyClass.DEFAULT_SLEEP_TIME);
            }
            catch (InterruptedException ex2) {
                System.exit(-1);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This works fine, but I wonder if this could be done better, perhaps with an `ExecutorService` as I (and my IDE) don't like `Thread.sleep()` in a `while (true)` loop.

I have read a lot of questions and their answers about `ScheduledExecutorService` and task management, but I did not find this particular case since it's not really a schedule, I don't know if and when the task if going to end.

Comment: What about using a timer?

Comment: I read that `Executor` should be used instead as it is the prefered API to do these kind of things now.

Comment: To be perfectly honest, I think this model is dying out. Rather than constantly checking for something, set up a callback when something does arrive.

Comment: so what is the problem with having Thread.sleep() in a while loop? as long as you know what you doing, its fine. ExecutorService is great if you don't know how many tasks needs to be done. but its fine for two threads

Comment: @nafas It works great, but NetBeans is warning me about this and I thought it could be done in a more proper way.

Comment: @christopher The thing is, I'm not really checking for something, it's just that if something goes wrong in the primary class, then I'll wait a minute and start the application again (depending on the error).

Comment: @Djon as I said its fine as long as you know what you are doing :). of course for someone inexperience that could lead to some disaster that's why netbeans 'warning'(not stoping) you.

Comment: ExecutorService is a good API to use when you want a thread pool to perform short-lived tasks.  I would not use an ExecutorService to execute a 'task' that does not normally ever complete.

Comment: @Djon by the way, using executor techinically would lead to same problem. its interesting why would netbeans is suggesting to use that instead.

Comment: What is the warning Netbeans gives?

Comment: Something like this should NOT be done to wait for a condition. Unless it's a very special condition. Namely the condition that the loop should end. More precisely: Such a look *can* be feasible, for example, as the main loop in a game (although the sleep time should be in sync with real time then!). For other use cases, a http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.html may be more appropriate.

Comment: @nafas @naveejr NetBeans warns me about `Thread.sleep() called in a loop.`, that's why I started to look for an alternative.

Comment: @Djon don't worry netbeans can be stupid sometimes, just trust ur instinct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a [`ScheduledExecutorService`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html):

```
ScheduledExecutorService s=Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(1);
s.scheduleWithFixedDelay(new Runnable() {
  public void run() {
    try {
      MyClass myClass = new MyClass();
      myClass.startInfiniteLoop();
    } catch(SomeException ex) {}
  }
}, 0, MyClass.DEFAULT_SLEEP_TIME, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
```

The key point is to use [`scheduleWithFixedDelay`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html#scheduleWithFixedDelay(java.lang.Runnable,%20long,%20long,%20java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit)) rather than `scheduleAtFixedRate` to ensure the specified time elapses *between* the subsequent executions just like with your `sleep` approach. However, note that even with “fixed rate” the new execution will not start when the old one has not finished yet. [It’s documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html#scheduleAtFixedRate(java.lang.Runnable,%20long,%20long,%20java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit)) says: “*If any execution of this task takes longer than its period, then subsequent executions may start late, but will not concurrently execute.*”

Further note that you still have to catch the exception like in my code example as otherwise the executor will cancel the scheduled task once it threw an uncatched exception.

Comment: That's what I was missing! _"between the termination of one execution and the commencement of the next"_

Answer (score 0):

If you can take the MyClass and rework it to have a Runnable that does what only one loop iteration of the MyClass would have done, then you can use a scheduling executor service, telling the service to run the Runnable once every time period.

--- Updated by request of a quick example ---

The following is not strictly correct Java code, it is pesudo-java.

```
 public class MyRepeatingTask implements Runnable {

    private final ScheduledThreadpoolExecutor executor;

    public MyRepeatingTask(ScheduledThreadpoolExecutor executor) {
      this.executor = executor;
    }

    public void run() {
      try {
        doMyVariableLengthThing();
        // alternatively, you could also schedule a new instance
        executor.schedule(this, 1, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
      } catch (Exception e) {
        cleanup();
      }
    }
 }
```

and then to start the ball rolling

```
 ScheduledThreadpoolExecutor executor = new ScheduledThreadpoolExecutor(1);

 executor.execute(new MyRepeatingTask(executor));
```

Comment: But the problem is that I have no idea how much it will take for it to end, at the beginning the application crashed a lot but now it can run for weeks before a problem occurs. If I schedule it the run once every time period I'm going to have multiple instances running at the same time right?

Comment: You didn't know how long it would take for the loop to go through an iteration before, so no change there!  You can always have the "iteration" of the loop schedule the next run too, if overlapping is really a concern.

Comment: I don't see what you mean, could you show me a quick example? This is basically a network application, and when something goes wrong it sleeps for a minute and restarts (i.e. connection, login and then while(true) read).

Comment: Added some pseudo code.  You'll probably find that you imagined it to be harder than it is.  It's really that easy.